# What is the sizeof(1), and does it differ from 1?

Tags: c, malloc

Correct me if I am wrong but does

```
malloc(1) // Mallocing 1 which is a int
```

equal

```
malloc( sizeof(1) )
```

Comment: I'd like to point out that the title and body of this question are different

Comment: Is the question in the title related to the text in the body? Please don't split up questions like that, put the *whole* question in the actual body text.

Comment: alright i rephrased the whole q

Comment: Why don't you see for yourself? `printf("%d %d\n", 1, int(sizeof(1)));`

Answer (score 6):

`void* malloc(size_t)` returns a pointer, and the memory after the pointer has been allocated with size equal to the argument fed into `malloc`. In your case, `malloc(1)` simply allocates a single byte, while `malloc(sizeof(int))` allocates 2 or 4 bytes.

`malloc(sizeof(1))` and `malloc(sizeof(int))` are equivalent statements but the latter is more apparent. Hence `malloc(1)` is not equivalent to `malloc(sizeof(1))` as `sizeof(1) == 4`. (Or sometimes 2, 8)

Comment: I don't think the OP meant `==` literally

Comment: in a 64 bit architecture, when compiling for 64bits, this line: `malloc(sizeof(int) )` will return a pointer to 8 bytes, located in the 'heap'.  I.E. `malloc()` always returns a pointer, if the operation failed, it returns NULL.  the type of the pointer is: `void*`,  The actual length of the allocated memory will depend on the underlying architecture.

Comment: @user3629249 It's harder to find a system where `sizeof(int) == 8` is true, than finding systems where `sizeof(int) == 2` is true. All modern home-PC systems, 64 or 32 bits, all have `sizeof(int) == 4`.

Comment: so malloc(1) allocates 1 byte, would that also mean malloc(2) allocates 2 bytes and so on ??

Comment: @Pyrons Yes. It might allocate more, but `n` bytes is guaranteed for `malloc(n)`.

Comment: I have a 64 bit system (which are becoming very common) If I compile for 32 bits, then a `int` is 4 bytes, however, if I compile for 64 bits, then a `int` is 8 bytes,  So a `int` that is 8 bytes is not that uncommon.

Comment: @user3629249  When you compile and `sizeof(int)==8`, what result for `sizeof(short)`?

Comment: @user3629249, I'd go so far as to say that 64-bit machines have become the norm, at least in the U.S.  But that doesn't change the fact that most compilers for such systems provide 32-bit `int`s whether building 32-bit or 64-bit binaries, at least by default.

Comment: Actually in C, sizeof(1) can equal 1.

Answer (score 3):

The size of an integer constant depends on the value of the constant and on a possible suffix. Integer constants are *at least* of the type `int` if it fits in an `int`, if the value of the constant is larger and don't fit in an `int` then `long` or `long long` are used. The constant `1` is small enough to fit in an `int` so `sizeof(1) == sizeof(int)` is true.

However, `malloc( sizeof(1) ) == malloc( sizeof(int) )` will *not* be true, since you allocate two different memory areas and each call will return different pointers. The *sizes* of those memory areas will be the same, but not the pointers returned by `malloc`. The exception being if both `malloc` calls fail and return `NULL`.

I know that you probably don't mean the comparison of the `malloc` calls literally, but in programming such things are important to spell out. Semantics is very important.

As for the question in your title, `malloc(1)` returns a pointer to *one* single byte.

Also be careful with assuming sizes, because `sizeof(int)` may actually *not* be four bytes. On small embedded platforms (or very old systems) it could be *two* bytes. And on future systems it might be eight or even more.

You might want to read e.g. [this `malloc` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/malloc) where it says that the argument is the number of ***bytes*** to allocate.

Comment: so malloc(1) allocates 1 byte?

Comment: @Pyrons In reality it allocates more, most likely, but you can't treat it like more was allocated as that would break the rules set up by the C specification. If you allocate one byte you should treat the returned pointer as a pointer to one single byte.

Comment: @Pyrons: Yes. `malloc(1)` allocates 1 byte.

Comment: The integer literal `1` is certainly of type `int`, but not *all* unsuffixed integer literals are of type `int`.  It depends on the value represented and on the base in which the number is expressed.  (C2011 6.4.4.1/5-6)

Comment: 1) "All integer literals, unless otherwise suffixed, are of type int" --> depends on value. `0x7FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF` is likely type `long long`.  2) Detail: no integer _literals_, but integer _constants_

Comment: Some current systems use 8-byte `int`

Comment: @chux in the C Standard they are called "integer constant", however IMO that is a bit confusing as they are not `const`, and not the same as a constant integer . Other related languages use the term "literal".

Comment: @M.M Systems that use an 8-bit `int` are significantly not C compliant.  (I have used them too.)  At best the language used is then _C-like_.

Comment: @M.M Yes of course, but what is a factor of 8 between compatriots? ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Integer constants such as `1` have their own type just as variables do. In this case `int`.

Meaning that `sizeof(1)` is equivalent to `sizeof(int)`.

So `malloc(1)` means "allocate 1 bytes", while `malloc(sizeof(1))` means allocate as many bytes as the size of an int.